# request-promise assume http, https

Tags: node.js, request-promise

In nodejs, is thre any way for the request-promise npm package, when i do a request to assume the http or https prefix ? Is there any option for that ? Like for example in jquery when you write an ajax request exactly like that '//myawesomewebsite.xom/givemedata', jquery assumes by its self the prefix http or https and the url becomes 'https://myawesomewebsite.xom/givemedata' or 'http://myawesomewebsite.xom/givemedata' according to the support of the requested server or whatever.
Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you can just request with http and eventually the server redirect you with https if it's supported

Comment: as far as I checked out the request-promise library don't default anything, you should explicitly specify your URL. as pointed out if the server supports redirect it could handle it.

Comment: thanks for you answer Mehari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way for the request-promise npm package, when i do a request to assume the http or https prefix ? Is there any option for that ?

No.  That feature is not built into request-promise.  It expects a fully qualified URL to be the target.  On the server-side, there are no "defaults" like there are on the browser side, probably because the browser operates in a "page" context which offers an intelligent default, but the server does not have such a default context.

You could implement a wrapper for request-promise that looked at any URL passed in and, if it was prefixed with `//`, it would change it to whatever you want the default protocol to be.  Then, you could use your wrapper function instead.

FYI, there is no simple way to determine which protocol the target server supports ahead of time.  You'd have to know already which protocol to use or you'd have to implement some scheme that tries `https` and if that fails, then tries `http`, but that would not perform as well as just knowing ahead of time which is the appropriate protocol to use.